# How to get data from MatDialog?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am following the documentation in [here](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview). 
I can pass data to the dialog but I am not getting data from it.
I am getting undefined result on .afterClose().subscribe() instead.
What am I missing? I am guessing there is something I need to do in the dialog's template but the documentation above does not provide an example for it.
Here's my code:

```
import {Component, Inject, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material';

import {MySavior} from '../shared/my-savior';
import {Savior} from '../../savior/shared/savior';
import {SaviorDataService} from '../../savior/shared/savior-data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-room-savior-select-dialog',
  template: 'my data name: {{data.name}}'
})
export class MySaviorSelectDialogComponent {
  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MySaviorSelectDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {}

  onClose(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-room-my-savior',
  templateUrl: './my-savior.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-savior.component.css']
})
export class MySaviorComponent implements OnInit {

  saviors: Savior[] = [];
  mySaviors: MySavior[] = [];

  constructor(private saviorDataServ: SaviorDataService, public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    ...
  }

  openSelectDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MySaviorSelectDialogComponent, {data: {name: 'test'}});
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('result ' + result); //i got result undefined 
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figure it out after I notice that we can pass data on MatDialogRef.close().

```
onClose(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close('pass data here');
}
```

The documentation only provide onNoClick() function which incidentally does not need to pass any data. The onOkClick() , on the other hand, I think should be more or less like the onClose() above. I don't know why they don't include it in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Component({ 
  selector: 'app-my-room-savior-select-dialog', 
  template: 'my data name: {{data.name}}' 
}) 

export class MySaviorSelectDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  name: string;

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef, @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) 
   public data) {}

  ngOnInit() { this.name = this.data.name; console.log(this.name); }
}
```

Comment: Explain your Answer more.

Answer (score 1):

There's another way if you want to return data depending on how you close the dialog, e.g. if you have a "Save" button in your dialog and don't want to save when you close it in another way like a "Cancel" button, clicking outside or pressing *Esc*:

From the documentation:

> mat-dialog-close  [Attr] Added to a , makes the button close
> the dialog with an optional result from the bound value.

So in the MySaviorSelectDialogComponent HTML markup use

```
<button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Cancel</button>
<button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="data">Save</button>
```

to make "Cancel" return null and "Save" return the data property.